# streaming video - Fatal error: Allowed memory exhausted - memory_limit ok

Tags: php, iis, video-streaming, memory-limit

I have a site on IIS 10 and PHP 7 where I want to serve up to 1 GB videos

On IIS I set

```
Maximum allowed content length: 1073741824
```

In php.ini I set

```
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

and since php Documentation says:

> "Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size"

```
memory_limit = 1025M
```

upload is ok , but reading a 0.5 GB video on this line:

```
$fp=fopen($file,"r"); while(!feof($fp)) {echo fread($fp,filesize($file)); flush();} fclose($fp);
```

I get

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 539267072 bytes)
```

though phpinfo() returns me the correct values, for debug I also tried

```
ini_set('memory_limit',-1);
```

but nothing changed

why I get this error?

must use all this memory to serve a video?

is there a better way for streaming videos?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

the code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);
$file="video.mp4";
if(file_exists($file))
{

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    $fp=fopen($file,"r"); while(!feof($fp)) {echo fread($fp,filesize($file)); flush();} fclose($fp);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Is output buffering in use on this page?

Comment: yes , I'll post full page code later

Comment: Well, there lies your problem then. flush() doesn't push the content to the user if there's an output buffer in the way. So, you've opened the file, and are holding it in memory (0.5GB). At the same time, you're pushing that file into the output buffer, which is being held in memory (Another 0.5GB). You've also got the memory being used by the rest of your script. Total: More than 1GB of memory consumed.

Comment: I updated with the code , what's wrong in it ? and I shouldn't get the error using 
ini_set('memory_limit',-1);

Comment: @Scoots I didn't understand your comment , there is something wrong in the code? Thanks